# JFLEX AND CUP, cannot make it work correctly

Tags: flex-lexer, jflex, cup

I'm working with jflex and cup, trying to make a html parser,
but can't make it work correctly,

Netbeans, the compile process dont stop, always continues, 
Can't add more "tokens" correctly in the parse tree,
Also can't add space in "TEXTO" , this break the entire tree

lexicoh.jlex

```
      package compiladorhtml;
      import java_cup.runtime.*;

      %%

      %class Lexer 
      %line
      %column
      %cup

      %{   
          private Symbol symbol(int type) {
              return new Symbol(type, yyline, yycolumn);
          }
          private Symbol symbol(int type, Object value) {
              return new Symbol(type, yyline, yycolumn, value);
          }
      %}

      LineTerminator = \r|\n|\r\n
      WhiteSpace     = {LineTerminator} | [ \t\f]
      texto = [a-zA-Z0-9_]*

      %%

      <YYINITIAL> {
         "::"                { System.out.print("<"); return symbol(sym.INI);}
         "ENCA"              { System.out.print("HEAD>"); return symbol(sym.HEAD);}
         "/"                 { System.out.print("</");  return symbol(sym.FIN);}
         {texto}             { System.out.print(yytext()); return symbol(sym.TEXTO);}
         {WhiteSpace}        { /* just skip what was found, do nothing */ }   
         "&&"                  { System.out.print(""); return symbol(sym.FINAL); }   
      }
      [^]                    { throw new Error("Illegal character <"+yytext()+">"); }
```

sintaticoh.cup

```
                package compiladorhtml;
                import java_cup.runtime.*;

                parser code {:

                    public void report_error(String message, Object info) {

                        StringBuilder m = new StringBuilder("Error");

                        if (info instanceof java_cup.runtime.Symbol) {

                            java_cup.runtime.Symbol s = ((java_cup.runtime.Symbol) info);

                            if (s.left >= 0) {                

                                m.append(" in line "+(s.left+1));   

                                if (s.right >= 0)                    
                                    m.append(", column "+(s.right+1));
                            }
                        }

                        m.append(" : "+message);

                        System.err.println(m);
                    }

                    public void report_fatal_error(String message, Object info) {
                        report_error(message, info);
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                :};



                terminal          INI, HEAD, TEXTO, FIN, FINAL;
                non terminal Object expr_list, expr_part;
                non terminal String expr;

                expr_list ::= expr_list expr_part | expr_part;

                expr_part ::= expr:e;

                expr ::=  INI HEAD 
                        | TEXTO 
                        | FIN HEAD
                        | FINAL;
```

java Main

```
                 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {

                        //CreateFiles();

                        //EJECUTAR PARA VER SI FUNCIONA, YA LO VI Y FUNCIONA
                        File fichero = new File("fichero.txt");
                        PrintWriter writer;
                        try {
                            writer = new PrintWriter(fichero);
                            writer.print("::ENCA NOMBRE ENCABEZADO /ENCA &&");
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                            System.out.println(ex);
                        }
                        Lexer thisscanner = new Lexer(new FileReader("fichero.txt"));
                        parser thisparser = new parser(thisscanner);
                        thisparser.parse();

                    }

                    public static void CreateFiles() {
                        String filelex = "path\\lexicoh.jlex";

                        File file = new File(filelex);
                        jflex.Main.generate(file);

                        String opciones[] = new String[5];
                        opciones[0] = "-destdir";
                        opciones[1] = "path";
                        opciones[2] = "-parser";
                        opciones[3] = "parser";
                        opciones[4] = "path\\sintacticoh.cup";
                        try {
                            java_cup.Main.main(opciones);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(CompiladorHTML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                    }
```

thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should do this:

for {texto}, since it is a string composed by text and number, you should redefine it in this way:

```
{texto} { System.out.println (yytext()); return new symbol(sym.TEXTO, new String (yytext())); }
```

Then, if the program doesn't stop, there could be some problems during the read of the source file.